# Insert element to start of sublist in list of lists

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm having a little trouble with an assignment. I have to create a procedure that requests a list of lists and an element and proceeds to add the element to the first position in every sublist. I managed to do that and it looks like this:

```
(define (add-element lst elem)
   (foldr cons lst (list elem)))

(define (insert-first lst1 x)
  (cond
   [(empty? lst1) empty]
   [else (local [(define insert (add-element(first lst1) x))]
        (cons insert (insert-first (rest lst1) x)))]))
```

So if you were to type `(insert-first '((a b) (c d))` you'd end up with `(list (list 'x 'a 'b) (list 'x 'c 'd))`

Only problem is that I'm required to code the procedure using `map` and `local`. The latter one I think I accomplished but I can't for the life of me figure out a way to use `map`.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(define (insert-first elt lst)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (cons elt x))
       lst))
```

then

```
(insert-first 'x '((a b) (c d)))
=> '((x a b) (x c d))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (insert-first lst elem)
   (foldr (lambda (x y) (cons (cons elem x) y)) '() lst))
```

Close to your solution, but map is more naturally suited to the problem than a fold, since you want to want to do something to each element of a list. Use fold when you want to accumulate a value by successively applying a function to elements of that list.

Answer (score 0):

[`foldr` embodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Folds_as_structural_transformations) a certain recursion pattern,

```
(foldr g init [a,b,c,...,z]) 
= (g a (foldr g init [b,c,...,z]))
....
= (g a (g b (g c ... (g z init) ...)))
```

if we manually expand the `foldr` call in your `add-element` function definition, we get

```
  (add-element lst elem)
  = (foldr cons lst (list elem)) 
  = (cons elem (foldr cons lst '()))
  = (cons elem lst)
```

then, looking at your `insert-first` function, we see it is too following the `foldr` recursion pattern,

```
(insert-first lst1 x) 
= (foldr (lambda(a r)(cons (add-element a x) r)) empty lst1) 
= (foldr (lambda(a r)(cons (cons x a) r)) empty lst1)
```

But `(foldr (lambda(a r) (cons (g a) r)) empty lst) === (map g lst)`, because to combine sub-terms with `cons` is to build a list, which is what `map` does; and so we get

```
(insert-first lst1 x) = (map (lambda(a)(cons x a)) lst1)
```

and so we can write

```
(define (insert-first lst1 x)
  (local [(define (prepend-x a) (cons ... ...))]
    (map ... ...)))
```